# Converting ANSI to UTF-8 in shell

Tags: bash, shell, csv, utf-8, iconv

I'm making a parser (1 csv to 3 csv) script and I have a problem.
I am French so in my language I have letters like: `é è à ....`

A customer sent me a csv file that Linux recognizes as "unknown-8bit" (ansi I guess).

In my script, I'm writing 3 new csv files. But ViM creates them as ISO latin1 because it's close to what it got in the entry, but my `é,è,à...` are broken. I need UTF-8.

So I tried to convert the first ANSI csv to UTF-8 :

```
iconv -f "windows-1252" -t "UTF-8" import.csv -o import.csv
```

The problem is that it breaks my CSV. It's now on only one row. But my special chars are ok. Is there a way to convert ANSI to UTF-8 and keeping my rows?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Put the output into another file. Don't overwrite the old one.

```
iconv -f "windows-1252" -t "UTF-8" import.csv -o new_import.csv
```

`iconv` fails when reading and writing to the same file.

Comment: Use sponge from moreutils (additional Unix utilities) to keep the same name like so: `iconv -f "windows-1252" -t "UTF-8" import.csv | sponge import.csv`

Comment: I needed to convert Czech subtitles, so I had to use: `CP1250` as input encoding.

Comment: for me worked  the following

iconv -f "windows-1252" -t "UTF-8" import.csv > new_import.csv