# "&nbsp;" in JSX file being translated to "Â" in some browsers

Tags: reactjs, cordova, webpack, character-encoding, jsx

Presumably related to UTF8 conversion, but I have no idea where or why the conversion is taking place or how to disable it:  if I have a JSX file that includes "`&nbsp;`" in a text XML node, then when that node is rendered *in some browsers* the result is "Â" rather than the non-breaking space desired.

Research suggests that the direct cause of this is a unicode non-breaking space *character*, U+00A0 (rather than the *entity* I'm trying to use), is being translated to UTF-8 and giving the resulting byte sequence 0xC2 0x00, and then being interpreted as ISO-8859-1.  What I'd like to do is prevent this translation happening.

This doesn't seem to happen in desktop browsers at all, but the app I'm developing is an Apache Cordova app, and when the app is installed on a mobile the problem occurs, so either its the mobile browser itself, some aspect of using a WebView rather than a standalone browser, or part of the Cordova compilation process that's causing it.

My build process also uses webpack and babel, but I don't seem to have any settings relating to character set handling that might be relevant to this.

Example code that shows the fault:

```
function startApp () {
    ReactDOM.render (<span>&nbsp;</span>, document.getElementById('app'));
}
if (typeof document !== "undefined") document.addEventListener ("deviceready", startApp, false);
```

HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
        default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval' http://www.randomtext.me;
        script-src 'self' data: gap: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' connect.facebook.net;
        style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
        media-src *;
        img-src *;
        frame-src  'self' gap: *.facebook.com;
        connect-src * data:;">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/swiper.min.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        @font-face {
            font-family: "OpenSans-Regular";
            src: url("fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
        }
        @font-face {
            font-family: "OpenSans-Italic";
            src: url("fonts/OpenSans-Italic.ttf") format("truetype");
        }
        @font-face {
            font-family: "OpenSansCondensed-Light";
            src: url("fonts/OpenSansCondensed-Light.ttf") format("truetype");
        }
        @font-face {
            font-family: "OstrichSans-Medium";
            src: url("fonts/OstrichSans-Medium.otf") format("truetype");
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body><div class="Fill" id="app"></div></body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/styles.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>

</html>
```

### Update

I spotted [this blog post](http://chromakode.com/post/react-utf8) where somebody else has experienced this.  The suggested solution is using:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

in index.html.  This *would* work to solve the problem as I describe it, but I am also interested in a solution that won't prevent rendering of existing documents that use ISO-8859-1 as their encoding.

Comment: I have actually solved this problem by translating my existing documents to UTF8, but I'm going to leave this question open in case anyone discovers a solution that doesn't involve either switching character encodings or hacking around the system in potentially dangerous ways to avoid the issue.

Comment: hi @jules, how did you translate your documents to UTF8? I tried by setting `<meta charSet='utf-8' />` but didn't solve the issue

Comment: @mikey - I used `iconv` to convert the files -- see the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20263909/converting-ansi-to-utf-8-in-shell -- then set my server to add "charset=utf-8" to the content type headers (https://gist.github.com/softprops/741574).

Answer (score 4):

I had problem with this entries too.

Check this question:[&nbsp jsx not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37909134/nbsp-jsx-not-working).

You can use dangerouslySetInnerHTML

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: 'Select Scenario: &nbsp;'}} />
```

Or

```
<h1>Code {' '}</h1>
```

Comment: Using "dangerouslySetInnerHTML" for such a routine purpose is a rather obscure solution.  The word "dangerous" is included in the method name for a reason.  The second suggested solution doesn't appear to actually produce a non-breaking space, but rather a second whitespace character that doesn't coalesce with the first; while this may be useful sometimes, I really *do* need non-breaking spaces.  `&nbsp;` translating to `Â` is clearly a *bug*, and there must be some solution to it that doesn't involve such convoluted processes...?!

Comment: Agree with you what i wrote is workaround and i do not like this behavior too.

Comment: @Jules it is not a bug.  https://shripadk.github.io/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html -- also "dangerously" is there as a reminder that it _can_ be dangerous.  However in this case, simply including `nbsp&;` it is obviously not.

Comment: @Madbreaks - I don't see anything there that suggests this isn't a bug.  It clearly states that HTML entities can be used in text included in the JSX file (although they can't be dynamically included), but what is not documented (and really shouldn't be the case) is that when the charset of the output HTML is not UTF-8 the result is a mangled encoding that simply doesn't work correctly.

Comment: `UTF-8` is only a consideration if you write the unicode character directly into your JS.  `&nbsp;` isn't that. _"If you want to display an HTML entity within dynamic content, you will run into double escaping issues as React escapes all the strings you are displaying in order to prevent a wide range of XSS attacks by default."_ -- documented, not a bug.